# Geometry problem about proving midpoint using complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

The original question is as follows,

> Let O be the center of a circle passing through points A, B, C and let
> AD be a diameter of the circle. Let the tangent line at D to the
> circle intersect line BC at P. Let line OP intersect line AC and AB at
> M and N respectively. Prove that O is the midpoint of MN.

This is what I have come up with the picture,[image]

I have the equation of line of BC is $Z+BC\cdot\overline{\rm Z}=-BC$.

And the equation of the tangent line at D is $Z+D^{2}\overline{\rm Z}=2D$

After assuming it is a unit circle, I expressed point B and C as $e^{i\alpha}$ and $e^{i\beta}$ respectively. But I am stuck afterward.

I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Sorry, was it stipulated that you use complex numbers?

Comment: @Deepak It is recommended by our teacher.He suggest us to use complex number to approach this question.

Answer (score 2):

Lower case letters denote the affixes of complex numbers. Let $O$ be the center of the unit circle $(ABC)$ and let line $AD$ be the real axis. So, $a=-1$ and $d=1$.

Considering the equation of line $DP$, $p$ satisfies:

$$p+\overline{p} = 2 \tag{1}$$

Since $p$ also lies on line $BC$:

$$p+bc\overline{p}=b+c \tag{2}$$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously:

$$p=\frac{-2bc+b+c}{1-bc} \tag{3}$$

The equation of the line containing $o$ (origin) and $p$ is:

$$z=\frac{2bc-b-c}{-2+c+b} \cdot \overline{z} \tag{4}$$

So, $n$ satisfies $(4)$:

$$n=\frac{2bc-b-c}{-2+c+b} \cdot \overline{n} \tag{5}$$

Since $n$ also lies on line $AB$ :

$$n=\overline{n}b-1+b \tag{6}$$

Solving $(5)$ and $(6)$ simultaneously:

$$n=\frac{-2bc+b+c}{b-c}  \tag{7}$$

Likewise, $m$ satisfies $(4)$:

$$m=\frac{2bc-b-c}{-2+c+b} \cdot \overline{m} \tag{8}$$

Since $m$ also lies on line $AC$:

$$m=\overline{m}c-1+c \tag{9}$$

Solving $(8)$ and $(9)$ simultaneously:

$$m=\frac{2bc-b-c}{b-c}  \tag{10}$$

Considering $(7)$ and $(10)$:

$$\fbox{$n+m=0$} \; \;\; \blacksquare$$

Comment: +1, Nice answer!

Comment: @AméricoTavares Thank you :)